# Google translate API TranslationException message list

Tags: google-api, google-translate

I am using google translate API for the translation. In the translation, if any exception occurs, it throws TranslateException with a message.I have added logs in my code which are:

```
com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: Daily Limit Exceeded
com.google.cloud.translate.TranslateException: User Rate Limit Exceeded
```

and text too long when char limit exceeds 5000 characters in a single request.

I searched in google [API docs](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.21.1/apidocs/index.html) for TranslateException but didn't find.I want a list of all messages like User Rate Limit Exceeded, Daily Limit Exceeded etc.